# In terms of performance, which processor is more suitable?

Tags: performance, cpu, upgrade

My computer specs:

```
Motherboard: Gigabyte GA-945PL-S3
OS: Microsoft Windows 7 Ultimate
CPU Socket: LGA775
CPU: Intel® Core™2 Duo Processor E4300 (2M Cache, 1.80 GHz, 800 MHz FSB)
```

After I bought new hard drive (Western Digital 250GB, 7200rpm, 32MB, Sata III, Caviar Blue, WD2500AAKX) I saw that my processor temperature started to raise to higher value then before. Now while surfing internet it goes to 70°C.

Cleaned my motherboard - nothing;
cleaned fan - nothing;
replaced thermal paste - nothing;
replaced thermal paste with care - still nothing.

So I went to friend just to check if he doesn't have any spear fan, and he did. But with fan he had another processor that he didn't need and he wanted to give it to me, but I told him that I will think about this.

So my [CPU](http://ark.intel.com/products/28024/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-E4300-%282M-Cache-1_80-GHz-800-MHz-FSB%29), he's [CPU (Intel® Pentium® D Processor 820 
(2M Cache, 2.80 GHz, 800 MHz FSB))](http://ark.intel.com/products/27512/Intel-Pentium-D-Processor-820-%282M-Cache-2_80-GHz-800-MHz-FSB%29).

```
Question: which proccesor is better for gaming and for recording games?
```

Answer (score 2):

These benchmark numbers were taken from Passmark (www.passmark.com). Personally, I throw away or donate any computer that generally has a CPU rating of less than 3,000. They are generally older than what I have use for.

To answer your question, though the PentiumD has a higher clock speed, overall it is a slower processor. You're better off sticking with your Core2Duo. However, if you come across a few hundred bucks, you're much better off investing in an Ivy Bridge. The speed difference is noticeable.

Newer Rigs

```
10,421 - Intel Core i7-3770 @ 3.40GHz       $319.99**
7,942 - Intel Core i5-3570 @ 3.40GHz        $214.99*
4,336 - AMD Phenom II X4 970        $109.99*
```

Your Rigs

```
1,051 - Intel Core2 Duo E4300 @ 1.80GHz
741 - Intel Pentium D 2.80GHz
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd say yours (according to passmark yours scores 1050 points against 701 for the pentium D 820). Since you say you are having problems with it, even after replacing fans and thermal paste, it might be your CPU is just malfunctioning.

Answer (score 0):

Both are horrible sorry to say.

It's basically time to build a new rig or throw in a overpriced intel chip in the outdated mobo.

A AMD cpu base system would be easier on the wallet for about the same performance. The new AMD FX chips are not the promised intel killer but they are priced right.

You wanna play you gotta pay.

Comment: Rude - but I agree :D

Comment: lol Sorry Robert. I did say I was sorry in the original post. I know what it's like. I had a HP P4 for 5 years before I build my new rig, had to save for 2 years. I'm just being honest. You need a new cpu, whether it be intel or AMD is personal preference, but along with a new cpu usually needs to come a new mobo, then a new video card and a new power supply. And if you go that far you might as well start fresh, new everything. If our wages went up according to inflation we'd all be able to build a new rig every year, but even though prices have dropped on tech it's still spendy to build a pc.